# Python Dash graph line label cutoff

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I'm using Dash to make a line graph of a boolean Pandas series, and the label is cutoff.

**Anyone know how to fix the cutoff label?**

[image: graph with label cutoff]

Here's my code for the layout:

```
    layout = dict(
        margin=dict(l=25, r=25, b=40, t=40),
        hovermode="closest",
        legend=dict(font=dict(color='#7f7f7f'), orientation="h"),
        title=gateway_obj.location,
        font=dict(
            color="#7f7f7f"
        ),
    )
```

and here's my code for the data:

```
    data = []
    for col in cols_chosen:
        data.append({
            'x': df['timestamp_local'],
            'y': df[col],
            'name': col,
            'type': 'scatter',
            'mode': 'lines',
            'line': {
                'shape': 'spline', 
                'smoothing': .2
            }, 
        })

    figure = {
        'data': data, 
        'layout': layout
    }
```

This chart plots other time series as well, but the boolean ones are the only ones giving me problems.

**Other, possibly relevant, information:**

The above code creates the figure for a Dash dcc.Graph() object, which is inside three Bootstrap HTML divs (container, row, and col). There's nothing special about the divs. I tried adding padding and margin on the divs and it just pushed the graph to the right without fixing the cutoff label.

Thanks!
Sean

Answer (score 2):

Silly me, I just had to add more margin to the layout's "margin" dictionary on the left:

margin=dict(***l=40***, r=25, b=40, t=40),

Problem solved... Here's the full layout now:

```
layout = dict(
    margin=dict(l=40, r=25, b=40, t=40),
    hovermode="closest",
    legend=dict(font=dict(color='#7f7f7f'), orientation="h"),
    title=gateway_obj.location,
    font=dict(
        color="#7f7f7f"
    ),
)
```

[image: picture showing label fixed]